# How do I use the non-convenience SCNGeometrySource initializer correctly?

Tags: swift, macos, scenekit

being new to Swift and SceneKit (not new to programming) and trying to get my first triangle displayed (in preparation of rendering a more complex procedurally generated geometry) I just stumbled over the following issue:

When I initialise the `SCNGeometrySource` as shown in the code below the triangle is in the wrong position. When using the shorter, commented out version to create `vertices` it works as expected. My understanding from the documentation and a couple of examples I found online was that these two should be equivalent.

Which embarrassing detail am I missing? Thanks!

```
      assert( MemoryLayout< SCNVector3 >.size == 24 )
      assert( MemoryLayout< SCNVector3 >.stride == 24 )
      let varray = [ SCNVector3( -3.0, -3.0, 0.0 ),
                     SCNVector3( 3.0, 3.0, 0.0 ),
                     SCNVector3( -3.0, 3.0, 0.0 ) ]
      let vdata = Data( bytes: varray, count: varray.count * 24 )
      print( "size: \(vdata.count), data: \(hexDump( vdata ) )" )  // size: 72, data: 00000000000008c000000000000008c0000000000000000000000000000008400000000000000840000000000000000000000000000008c000000000000008400000000000000000
      let vertices = SCNGeometrySource(data: vdata,
                                       semantic: .vertex,
                                       vectorCount: varray.count,
                                       usesFloatComponents: true,
                                       componentsPerVector: 3,
                                       bytesPerComponent: 8,
                                       dataOffset: 0,
                                       dataStride: 24 )
      // let vertices = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: varray)  // This works, the line above not
```

Edit: It works correctly when the input data consists of (vectors of) 32-bit floats (and all the parameters are adjusted accordingly).